# How to generate all multiplicative partitions of a number if I have a list of primes/exponents?

Tags: python, algorithm, number-theory

For instance, the number 24 has prime factorization 2^3*3^1, and can be written in the following ways

```
1*24
2*12
2*2*6
2*3*4
2*2*2*3
3*8
4*6
```

I may have missed one but you get the idea.

I tried looking into the other thread [How to find multiplicative partitions of any integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558292/how-to-find-multiplicative-partitions-of-any-integer) but couldn't understand the answers in all honesty.

I don't need anyone to write code for me but rather I could really use some help creating an efficient algorithm for this (probably something recursive?).

I am coding in Python.

Comment: Why on earth are there two votes to close? Can those who voted care to explain?

Comment: You can boil your problem down to finding all of the possible partitions of a list.

Comment: @Blender: I have a method for finding additive partitions of a number. Is this what you mean? If so, how does that relate to multiplicative partitions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem can be condensed into finding all of the [partitions of a set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set), as each factor (prime and composite) can be represented as the product of the elements of a subset that makes up your partition.

I would represent the factors of your number as a list `[2, 2, 2, 3]` (well, a set). Here are some possible partitions of this list:

- `[2] + [2, 2, 3]`
- `[2, 2] + [2, 3]`
- `[2] + [2] + [2, 3]`
- `[3] + [2] + [2, 2]`
- ...

If you multiply together each element of each subset, you will get a factor of the original number:

- `2 * 12`
- `4 * 6`
- `2 * 2 * 6`
- `3 * 2 * 4`

You might have to add in a special case for `1 * n`.

Here's a relevant question: [How can I maximally partition a set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618685/how-can-i-maximally-partition-a-set)

And another relevant link: [Generating the Partitions of a Set](http://compprog.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/generating-the-partitions-of-a-set/)

Comment: Does this require not only finding list partitions, but all permutations of partitions too?

Comment: Nope, just partitions. My examples were a little lazy, sorry. A partition is just a collection of subsets that, when combined, form the original set. A subset is just a set of elements that's contained within the original set (not in any specific order).

Comment: I have a generator that would yield, in the case of 24, which has four total nondistinct prime factors 2,2,2,3, of [1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2],
[2, 2],
[1, 3],
[4]
is this enough? Don't I have to swap all these around the prime factors every possible way?

Comment: @JohnSmith: What do the numbers in the output represent?

Comment: Additive partitions of 4 (to represent the different ways of clustering the primes) so [4] might correspond to (2*2*2*3) and [1,3] might correspond to (2)*(2*2*3) etc

Comment: @JohnSmith: That should work. I just realized that you can't have a set of sets in Python, which'll make things somewhat tricky.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Wait, no it won't. `frozenset` can be used for the inner sets instead: `frozenset([frozenset([3]), frozenset([2, 1])]) == frozenset([frozenset([1, 2]), frozenset([3])])`